# Sentence structure with an embedded question in a sentence

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, sentence, questions

There are several instances where we embed questions in a sentence, but what is the conventional structure of those embedded question? For example,

1. She asked if we still need a pen.
2. She asked do we still need a pen.

Which one is right and why?
As far as I know option 1 is right, but what is the grammatical explanation for that? Please elaborate.

Comment: Why do you think that option 1 is correct?

Comment: See [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100571/questions-in-indirect-speech-and-verb-tense-change).

Comment: I'd check [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9520/when-are-if-and-whether-equivalent). (2') would be the correct way to quote the question: << She asked/enquired, "Do we still need a pen?" >>.

Comment: @KillingTime beacuse in the book it was marked correct.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/608581/2085).

Comment: There's also [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152082/what-are-reasons-to-omit-quotation-marks-in-dialogue) about omitting quotation marks: if you're Cormac McCarthy then 2 is fine, if not then you might want to use quotes.

Comment: @ShivamRaghuwanshi This is a good example of textbooks that purport to teach English (and the teachers who write them). Most are pretty worthless; don't trust them.

Answer (score 1):

The first example is grammatical, but, crucially, one can use *whether* instead of *if*.

- *She asked **if** we still need a pen.*
- *She asked **whether** we still need a pen.*

*Whether* is the *Wh*-word for embedded yes/no questions.

- *Had you gone?*
- *She didn't know whether/if you had gone.*

Yes/no questions merely distinguish two alternatives, so it's easy to substitute a hypothetical *if* for *whether*. The important thing is that this is an embedded question complement (acting as the object of *ask*), and embedded questions require an introductory complementizer (usually a *Wh*-word, but *if* is allowed for yes/no embedded questions).

The second example is not grammatical because it doesn't follow the rule for how to embed a question as a complement clause. This doesn't follow the *Wh* rule; it just embeds the yes/no question as if it were a main clause, with *Do*-Support and Subject-Auxiliary inversion:

- **She asked do we still need a pen*.

This is not good writing style; it's close to a quotation, but not quite:

- *She asked "Do you still need a pen?"*

uses second person plural *you* instead of first person plural *we*, which is supplied by the reference in the embedded question.

In speech (but not writing), the second example could be grammatical, if it was intoned as a yes/no question, and intended to solicit an answer. It might be reported as

- *"She asked do we still need a pen?"*

if it expects the addressee to answer the question.
[Similar remarks hold for other embedded *Wh*-questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51126/15299).

Comment: 'We' could include 'she'.